# Primefaces Datatable in nested TabView

Tags: primefaces, datatable, nested, tabview

I'm using pf4.0 and jsf 2.2 for my webapp. Now I have a nested TabView containing a second TabView with a datatable. Like this:

```
<p:tabView>
  <p:tab>
    <p:tabView>
      <p:tab>
        <p:dataTable>
          ....
        </p:dataTable>
       </p:tab>
    </p:tabView>
    ...
```

the problem now is that if i use a filter in the datatable the following js error occurs:Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'outerHeight' of undefined

Does anyone out there have a solution? Haven't found anything regarding to this problem :(

***UPDATE:***
I tried to reproduce the problem in an simple application and I found out, that this error only occures when scrollable=true and scrollHeight=250px is set. 
Anyone got an idea?

Comment: Could you create minimistic example, in which that error occurs for you, as well as provide your browser version?

Comment: hmm.. just did try to make a simple example, but the error doesn't occure now. Seems like I've done something wrong in my full example...

Comment: It's why minimal examples are good. Sometimes it's the missing braces somewhere in JavaScript part, sometimes some other trivial thing... If not trivial, you know there, what's the minimal circumstances to replicate that.

Comment: yeah I see, thank you so far. I found out what the real reason is, do you have any solution for this?

Comment: If your browser is on the supported list, write on PF forum because it can be a bug.

Comment: Already written in PF forum, but no response since 2 weeks now... Still not solved the problem

Comment: Note: The forum entry can be found [here](https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?t=37831), and the issue was opened [here](https://code.google.com/archive/p/primefaces/issues/6917). The issue was closed and not moved to GitHub because it should work with PrimeFaces 5.2.